# Activemq jolokia rest api for deleting a queue?

Tags: rest, activemq-classic, jolokia

Is there a way to delete a queue with ActiveMQ rest api on 5.9.0? I know you can purge a queue with

```
"http://" + host + ":" + port + "/api/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=" + queueName + ",destinationType=Queue,type=Broker/purge()";
```

But what is the one for deleting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the following URL pattern:

```
http://hostname:8161/hawtio/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=MyBroker/removeQueue(java.lang.String)/MyQueue
```

You can read about the format to access JMX operations thorugh jolokia [here](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html#exec).

Comment: Tried it. Error Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response.

Comment: My URL was: http://192.168.111.80:61616/hawtio/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost/removeQueue(java.lang.String)/0602f86e-86c5-4758-94aa-b2cb499997fd

Comment: 61616 is typically the openwire port, not the HTTP port. I verified the URL in my answer with a local default configured ActiveMQ 5.9.0. Of course, you have to change `MyBroker`and `MyQueue`aside from the port and hostname.

Comment: Do you have a curl command that worked for you? I get nothing but errors trying it.

Comment: This removes MyQueue. Some characters are escaped with backslash since i ran it on a mac terminal. 
`curl --user admin:admin http://localhost:8161/hawtio/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type\=Broker,brokerName\=localhost/removeQueue\(java.lang.String\)/MyQueue`

Comment: that java.lang.String stuff made mine fail on ActiveMQ 5.9.0. Once I removed that it worked:

Comment: Hmm. Odd, it works for me. It's great that you managed to get it working though.

Answer (score 1):

This one works.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=<brokerName>/removeQueue/<queueName>' --header 'Authorization: Basic <token>' \
```

Courtesy: [brettPorter](https://gist.github.com/brettporter/6788653)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java f'n that does it:

```
public static String removeQueue(String queueName) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException {

    String username = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    URI mqUrl = new URI( YOUR ACTIVE MQ URI HERE );
    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(mqUrl.getHost(), mqUrl.getPort(), "http");

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    final HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    String uri = "http://" + mqUrl.getHost() + ":" + mqUrl.getPort() + "/hawtio/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost/removeQueue/" + queueName;

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri), context);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }
    return IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
}
```